# How hard is it to find hotels / accommodation in Vietnam on arrival?

Tags: hotels, accommodation, vietnam, backpacking, asia

I will be travelling to Vietnam in around 9 months with my girlfriend and we are trying to figure out if we should book hotel rooms in advance or if it's a better idea to find accommodation when we arrive?

Here's a list of places we plan to visit:

- Hanoi
- Halong bay
- Hoi an
- Saigon – Ho Chi Minh City
- Dalat
- Phu quoc island

Given our itinerary would it be possible to just turn up and find places?

Comment: It’s probably always possible to find accommodation however short the notice is, but whether it can be found within your budget and preferred standard might be less certain depending on how flexible you’re willing to be, whether you’re travelling peak season etc. Another consideration would be how long you plan to stay in each location and how much of that time you’re willing to spend on searching for a place to stay. Your question might be too broad to answer in anything other than general terms.

Comment: It all depends on your budget, if you pre book you know what the expense will be but if you just show up you might get higher or lower cost based on occupancy for that specific time, I for one would always pre book so that I know whats my cost is before hand to avoid surprises

Comment: And one very important thing, if your GF is Vietnamese the hotels are extremely strict that you have to be married in order to stay in the same room, it is illegal for any vietnamese non married girl to stay with a man in the same room, so in order to avoid problems it is always best to pre book and ensure you book for two and make it clear you are brining your wife

Comment: @MattDouhan who said that? unmarried Vietnamese couples go to hotels all the time. There's no law forbidden that either. Sex before marriage is not illegal in Vietnam

Comment: @phuclv the hotel have told me multiple times meridian, Hyatt etc

Comment: @MattDouhan either they're telling BS or a joke, or you've misunderstood them. I'm sure none of the hotels say that in their websites, and you can't find that in the laws either. Prostitution OTOH is illegal, so police occasionally check hotel rooms to find out that couples are really lovers or married couples. If the only link between them is money (e.g. either can't answer some information about the other) then both of them and the hotel will be fined

Comment: @phuclv might be that they always assume a foreigner with a Vietnamese girl is prostitution not sure, it gets pretty annoying though for new hotels happened to me last time last year December in Da Nang at the Hyatt resort went with my gf and her family and they still made that point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is generally possible as there are a huge number of accommodations available. Unless you arrive during a really popular holiday, I would expect you to find *some* availability. Of course, it is impossible to say this with certainty. It will diminish your choices for sure though which will depend what you are looking for. The most desirable locations do get full though, particularly in less touristy cities that have a limited number of nice hotels.

The things to balance here are predictability, flexibility and cost. Reserving in advance guarantees your price in advance but if you book locally, you can often get a much cheaper rate than the same property online. I saw the average difference was around 50% by comparing with other travelers. One has to be really careful in Vietnam though because if you simply ask, there are people that charge double or triple on the account that you are not expected to know the real price. This is particularly true of transportation like Taxi and Motos.

If what you are looking for is to keep your itinerary flexible, then my recommendation is to book the few days of hotel at your arrival city ahead of time and then in Vietnam, while travelling, you book the next destinations as your schedule firms up. Booking via trusted locals can get you very good prices. This is often my strategy when there is time for flexibility. On the other hand, if your schedule is tight, book everything ahead and you won't waste time on location figuring how what is where and the fare price!

Keep in mind that taxis are *very* expensive in Vietnam and so if you need more of them because you saved a few dollars on a further hotel, then you will end up paying more.

Comment: Use apps like Grab, Gojek... to book taxis. They're much cheaper than traditional taxis

Answer (score 2):

In some places not frequented by foreign tourists it was very hard to find places last time I came to Vietnam around 2015. I crossed at a less popular border crossing from Cambodia or Laos and found none in the first town and had to continue on to the second or third town.

This will not happen in bigger places. In famous tourist destinations accommodation is easier to find but may be booked out. Try to check for holidays or events around the time you'll be there.

I often book just the first night to be safe and then wing it.